# Como remover o background azul do item da tabela quando selecionado?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt-5, widget

Eu tenho um `QTableWidget` e preciso que todos os items da tabela possuam a mesma cor de fundo. O problema é que quando um item é selecionado, ele fica com o *background* azul.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei o seguinte código no `stylesheet`, porém ele não funcionou:

```
QTableWidget {
    selection-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Minha dúvida é: como posso remover esse background azul quando o item é selecionado, utilizando o `stylesheet` em PyQT5?

Answer (score 1):

Isso é o QSS (Qt Style Sheets, um estilo vagamente semelhante ao CSS), para estilizar você pode (deve) consultar a documentação do Qt oficial (e não dos seus "wrappers"), no caso dos estilos para QSS:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html

No seu caso especifico você que estilizar os itens selecionados, então tem que usar os [**pseudo-states**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-pseudo-states) para obter o item em foco usando `:focus` e para obter os itens (ou outros sub-controles) deve usar a [**lista QSS de sub-controles**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-sub-controls), nesse caso creio ser o `::item`

```
QTableWiget::item:focus {
    selection-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Além disso você pode experimentar o `paintEvent`, para muitas coisas acaba sendo até mais simples que usar QSS, mas vai de caso a caso.

As únicas situações que não consegui customizar algo com QSS foi sobre elementos dentro do QWebView (QtWebkit), aonde tive que usar [**`QProxyStyle`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20909625/1518921), mas isso é porque eram elementos dos quais eu não tinha controle gerado a partir do motor de renderização HTML (Webkit).

Comment: Ele removeu o background, mas também "apagou" os textos. O texto do item não é mais visível. Além disso, a minha tabela tem cor diferente em cada linha, como na imagem da pergunta. Seria possível retirar esse background azul mantendo a cor atual do item?

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 experimenta o `background-color: transparent;`, assim que sobrar um tempo irei testar.